# Devise helpers are not available in cucumber step definitions

Tags: devise, cucumber

I'm using cucumber to test my rails 3.1 application and i'm using devise for authentication.
I need to test if current user email is the same with the one used during authorization.
The problem is that devise helpers are not available in cucumber step definition.

Is there any solution to make devise helpers available in cucumber step definitions?

i tried this:

```
Cucumber::Rails::World.send('define_method', 'current_user') do
    @current_user ||= (session[:user] && User.find(session[:user])) || :false
end
```

but that didn't help.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I would like to know if it is possible also.

Comment: Finally I could't find any solution. After authorization I had some text that could only be seen if you were authorized. So i just tested the presence of this text.

May be this will be helpful
http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/b1916a741670a3f3/d2ebae6576f333c9?pli=1

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm in a similar position checking for elements and not feeling like it's a good way to do things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to the step definitions file that needs to use it:

```
World(Devise::TestHelpers)
```

While this makes the 'sign_in' and 'sign_out' methods available, they can't actually be used from Cucumber, so this **DOES NOT WORK**. The comments at the top of devise's file says "Do not use Devise::TestHelpers in integration tests". See: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb

Unfortunately, cucumber steps don't have access to the web request object and session parameters. It appears the only way to do this is to repeatedly perform the login web requests at the start of each scenario. Boring. I find it odd that cucumber can directly manipulate the test rails app's database but not the web request/session. In any case, this *old* post shows a good example of refactoring steps to be in a module that can be shared by many steps easily: http://drnicwilliams.com/2009/04/15/cucumber-building-a-better-world-object/

If anyone else has an answer for how a scenario can set the logged in state without having to do all the capybara web calls, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this to stub log ins in Cucumber:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara

put the lines in support/env.rb:

`include Warden::Test::Helpers`

`After do
   Warden.test_reset!
 end`

then you can do:

`user = create :user
login_as :user, scope: :user`

**BUT**, the `login_as` helper does not redirect you to the next page after logging you in. It just logs you in.

So you must explicitly go to the next page you are testing as a logged in user.

So you must do another step to explicitly do that, e.g. `visit '/'`

Answer (score 0):

Something that may help is https://github.com/ngty/cross-stub - this allows you to stub methods cross process, which is necessary for cucumber testing sometimes